# Python: assign point to roads shapefile

Tags: python, geolocation, shapefile

I have some data points from gps data (Lat,Lon) and the relative `shapefile` of the area I am considering. So:

```
import pandas as pd
import shapefile
sf = shapefile.Reader('roadshape')
df = pd.read_csv('gpsdata.csv')
```

Now `df` contains the data I am analyzing is something like this:

```
 ID          x          y
3447    11.400427   48.816806
3448    11.400759   48.816772
3449    11.401424   48.816684
3450    11.401758   48.816631
3451    11.402090   48.816566
3452    11.402422   48.816490
```

I want to assign to each the respective `shapefile` segment. I am trying to do the following. I am considering the bounding box and I want to try to see in which bounding box the data points the data bar.

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
shapes = sf.shapes()
X =list()
Y=list()
for i in range(0,len(shapes)):
      X.append([shapes[i].bbox[0],shapes[i].bbox[2]])
      Y.append([shapes[i].bbox[1],shapes[i].bbox[3]])
dfs['X'] = X
dfs['Y'] = Y
```

Now how can I check in which bbox my points are? Where `dfs` is something like this

```
dfs = 
                 X                             Y
0   [10.9467244189, 10.9704393002]  [48.2671975178, 48.2697440003]
1   [11.5138847999, 11.5143541004]  [48.6497096997, 48.6515363002]
2   [11.4618209998, 11.4620896004]  [48.9305448001, 48.9307776004]
3   [10.6196591004, 10.6207268996]  [48.8635958001, 48.8665684003]
4   [10.652098, 10.6559025999]  [48.8005320998, 48.8042877999]
5   [11.1863882997, 11.1884544004]  [48.3726685999, 48.3738253996]
6   [11.1580075998, 11.1593822] [48.3785226999, 48.3791247996]
7   [11.1077987, 11.1112508996] [48.3829125003, 48.3830440999]
8   [11.0842697004, 11.0886483996]  [48.3840543003, 48.3879626001]
9   [11.0910959001, 11.0926532003]  [48.3903297003, 48.3916850002]
10  [11.4766434001, 11.4822778002]  [49.0389071001, 49.0399456003]
11  [11.7037148998, 11.7073818] [48.6927748996, 48.6961230001]
12  [11.7767894997, 11.7770049998]  [48.6279809001, 48.6279908997]
```

Comment: Do I understand right that shapes[i].bbox[0] is leftmost X coord, bbox[1] - top Y coord, bbox[2] - right X, bbox[3] - bottom Y. And these two points define bounding box? And as result you want to get dictionary (for example) which maps from each GPS point to corresponding BBOX ?

Comment: there are more robust module like shapely,fiona, ogr to handle geometry!

Comment: Have you any update ? you can adapt panda df (bounds) to my csv!

Comment: Is Slslam's solution fast enough for your application? Note: I know a faster approach.

Comment: Why are you asking for an answer from official sources?

Answer (score 3):

I would go for fiona,shapely and built-in csv!

Say i have two files:1) A line shapefile with several line records in it. 2) A csv file with three columns i.e. id, longitude(x), latitude(y)

**CSV file content (lat, long is UTM)-**

```
id,lat,long

0,207726.012448,2733349.10914
0,197599.591396,2730510.17345
0,203187.5176,2736670.5686
0,207301.877268,2730639.81898
0,200929.610894,2726377.9799
0,204604.214301,2737608.342
0,203780.386032,2734372.2709
0,203077.172106,2731166.44271
0,202477.371994,2728622.46292
0,202249.861606,2734889.33996
0,201794.840831,2732159.21531
```

Now below code generates bbox for each record of the line shapefile and checks what point of csv file is inside of that bbox after all it prints status!

```
import fiona
from shapely import geometry
import csv
csv_file = open(r"C:\data_test.csv",'rb')
reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
pnts = []
for i in reader:
    pnts.append ((i[1],i[2]))
bboxes = []   
fiona_collection = fiona.open(r"C:\Rd.shp")
for i in fiona_collection:
    bboxes.append(geometry.asShape(i['geometry']).bounds)


for i in pnts:
    for j in bboxes:
        shape = geometry.box(*map(float,j))
        pnt = geometry.Point(*map(float,i))
        if shape.contains(pnt):
            print "bbox {0} contains {1} ".format(j,i)
```

It prints-

```
bbox (197306.68136754428, 2729718.6493367185, 197823.7504301681, 2732035.118737273) contains ('197599.591396', '2730510.17345') 
bbox (202799.29018572776, 2728807.5534000006, 204604.21430105247, 2737608.342) contains ('203187.5176', '2736670.5686') 
bbox (202799.29018572776, 2728807.5534000006, 204604.21430105247, 2737608.342) contains ('203780.386032', '2734372.2709') 
bbox (202799.29018572776, 2728807.5534000006, 204604.21430105247, 2737608.342) contains ('203077.172106', '2731166.44271') 
bbox (201237.0747999996, 2727558.2885, 203336.7932000002, 2728807.5534000006) contains ('202477.371994', '2728622.46292')
```

**you can download test data at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0q0mimfj4v74om/gis.zip?dl=0)**.